# How can I open settings from my app in android with Titanium?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

The following code was working fine

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: 'android.settings.APPLICATION_SETTINGS',
});

intent.addFlags(Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

I took the code from the app sample https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti510.

Does the app need certain permissions to open settings in android 6.0?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was caused because I was using a incorrect activity, I have the function in other .js file as a helper. I realised because of this line :

```
// Get a reference to this activity (current activity)
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

So it was pointing to the current activity (Which was not actually a real one), and that's why it's never opened Settings, so what I did :

I passed as parameter my current activity

```
var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
openSettings(activity);
```

To my to the function that handles open settings. So my function :

```
function openSettings(activity) {
    var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action: 'android.settings.APPLICATION_SETTINGS',
    });

    intent.addFlags(Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the code to use is the following:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: activity, // e.g. "android.settings.APPLICATION_SETTINGS"
});
intent.addFlags(Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Where the activity is a value specified here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

In addition, if you want to open the app settings page, use the following code:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS",
    data: "package:com.example.myapp"
});
intent.addFlags(Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

where `com.example.myapp` is the package name of your app.

If you wish to open the app settings page for the app you are currently on, you can do the following:

```
data: "package:" + Ti.App.id
```